# Receiving a badge does not correspond to it's description

Tags: feature-request, badges

Today I answered a question for the first time (which made me very happy)
and received some badges.
One of them looks strange.
<kbd>Teacher</kbd> badge description says:  "Answer a question with score of 1 or more." However, the question I answered has 0 score (I am still happy for answering it :)
So it must be a bug, either in giving the badge or in the badge description.

Comment: The badge is for answering a question and your *answer* scoring one or more. I can see where the wording is very confusing though.. Perhaps SE should change it. In that case I recommend [edit]ing your question to make it a [meta-tag:feature-request] for better wording.